# Middleman render partial from absolute path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, middleman

I'm writing a middleman extensions but having trouble re-using the `render_partial` method with an erb file path outside of the main application.

Trying to do so always gives me the error

`Cannot locate partial ...`

I believe this is because it only accepts *relative* paths from the application root.

Is there a way i can render partials with absolute paths in Middleman?

I can get around the issue by requiring Erb and doing my own rendering however I'm really keen to keep the Middleman `Context` when rendering my extension partials.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

It turn's out this is not currently possible with Middleman v4. [This line of code](https://github.com/middleman/middleman/blob/7c968b9572923fd0f7fb176ca8e52a91727adf84/middleman-core/lib/middleman-core/template_context.rb#L106) will only resolve relative file paths.

My work around was to write my own mini helper class that utilises [ERB](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) to render partials from absolute paths. I was able to keep the Middleman template context by using delegates on the @app instance.

Comment: Did you try to use `render file: "path/to/file"` instead to `render partial: `?

Answer (score 2):

try using this instead of render_partial

```
<%= partial 'partial/yourpartialname' %>
```

where yourpartialname should be in the format of _yourpartialname.html.erb

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks taking the time to answer.. unfortunately this only works with relative paths to the application root :(